# Changing body color conditionally in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8

I am working on a angular app. I want to change background color of  body conditionally when my flag is true. In my css, I have following

```
body {
 backgraound-color: blue;
 }
```

Now this color gets applied to full body of page. But when my flag is true, I want to change the background color of page. Generally when I have to change background color conditionally, I  use [ngClass] but in this case I am not getting how I can apply [ngClass] on body. How I can change background color of body conditionally?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **ngClass** for this. It is quite simple. In your app.component.html file wrap all DOM elements in a div element and add CSS conditionally there.

**app.component.html***

```
<div [ngClass] ="{'bodyClass1':flag ,'bodyClass2':!flag}" >
.
.
.
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.bodyClass1{
  background: skyblue;
}
.bodyClass2{
  background: red;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import ...
..
..
.
flag: boolean = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngStyle] like as below

- In your HTML =>

  ```
  <body [ngStyle]="{'background-color': color ? 'red' : 'green' }"> your body content</body>
  ```
- In your component.ts
  define variable

  color =false;
  (using a function change the value of this variable as you need)

Or else if you are using [ngClass]

```
 <body [ngClass]=" color ? 'yourcssClass1' : 'yourcssClass2' "> your body content</body>
```

Comment: I don't have body  tag in my html. when we define body in css it automatically gets applied to whole body of that page.

Comment: yes remove it and use a custom two classes like yourcssClass1 { background-color: blue; } yourcssClass2 {  background-color: red; } and use that class as above in your html element or use [ngStyle] like above. You can use both [ngClass] and [ngStyle] in any HTML element

Comment: If you are not clear check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3nv1a

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

ngOnInit(){
   this.document.body.classList.add('className');
}
```

or you can use Renderer2

```
    constructor(private store: Store, private render: Renderer2) {
    this.render.addClass(document.body,'className')
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div [ngClass] ="{'class1':flag ,'class2':!flag}" >
.
.
.
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.class1 {
    body {
     background-color: blue;
    }
}

.class2 {
   body {
    background-color: orange;
   }
}
```

**Component:**

```
.
.
.
.
flag: boolean = false;
```